# The viewport display/style of my rig has changed, and I can't work out why

Tags: 3d-view, bones, rigify

Originally the generated rig had the circle/square display. However, it has changed now to orchethedral looking bones. I cannot work out why this has changed, nor how to get it back. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
[image: Original rig display]

[image: New rig display]

Comment: Can you add an image of the Outliner? - The properties panel on the first image shows that "rig" is selected and the second one shows "rig.05". The "rig" one also has one extra bone layer selected (bottom row, fourth from the right).

Comment: Looks like the bone's custom shapes are missing. Usually, there is a collection named "WGTS-rig" in the Outliner that contains them. They are disabled in the viewport and unselectable by default so you cannot delete them accidentally. The widget names all begin with "WGT-...". Are they still there? -- If you select a bone in *Pose* mode, you can check the custom shape in the *Bone Properties* tab in the *Viewport Display > Custom Shape* section.